# getopt_long could not be resolved in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, getopt, getopt-long

Using the  in a C++ program, Eclipse CDT marks `getopt_long` as "could not be resolved". The code compiles and runs fine using **g++ program.cpp**. Has this something to do with the Eclipse build set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356425

Comment: In case link dies: "I too have a similar problem on Ubuntu with gcc 4.5.2. Adding getopt.h to the indexer solved the problem for me."